# Show forms on separate screens when launching application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multiscreen

I have two form and two screens in a .Net application.

When I run the program, I want to specify where the forms are located: the main form must run on first screen and second form must run on second screen.

How can I specify the screen location for forms?

Comment: Please add code of what you already have tried to accomplish this.  Also, how was this [asp-classic] if it is also [.net]?  Is this an App or desktop application?  I will assume that is win forms.

Answer (score 4):

All you need to setup `form.Location = new Point(X,Y);`

All screens are located on the same coordinate grid with 0,0 point on the top left corner of the primary screen.

You can use `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens` to get positions and sizes (in `Bounds` property of a screen) to decide where to put your form. Note that screen on the left or above the main screen has negative coordinates of top-left corner.